Adding Image into Excel using OpenXML
Using OpenXML 3.0.2, everything works fine, the images seems like added into the Excel file (judging by the file size increased), the Excel can be opened and view without any problem. But the image is missing.
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

public static void Test()
{
    using var Doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("Test.xlsx", true);
    var nDoc = Doc.Clone("Test1.xlsx");

    var wss = nDoc.WorkbookPart!.Workbook
        .GetFirstChild<Sheets>()!.Elements<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault()!;
    var ws = (WorksheetPart)(nDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(wss.Id!.Value!));

    DrawingsPart dp = null!;
    ImagePart ip = null!;

    if (ws.DrawingsPart != null) dp = ws.DrawingsPart;
    else
    {
        dp = ws.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
        ws.Worksheet.Append(new Xdr.WorksheetDrawing());
    }

    ip = dp.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);

    var img = File.ReadAllBytes("diet.png");
    using var ms = new MemoryStream(img);
    ip.FeedData(ms);

    AddImageToSheet(dp, ip, 2, 2);
    nDoc.Save();
}

private static void AddImageToSheet(DrawingsPart drawingsPart, ImagePart imagePart, int col, int row)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(imagePart.GetStream());
    long imageWidth = image.Width * 9525; // Convert pixels to EMUs
    long imageHeight = image.Height * 9525; // Convert pixels to EMUs

    // Assuming standard cell size (adjust as needed)
    long cellWidth = 64 * 9525; // 64 pixels
    long cellHeight = 20 * 9525; // 20 pixels

    // Center image within cell
    long offsetX = (cellWidth - imageWidth) / 2;
    long offsetY = (cellHeight - imageHeight) / 2;

    var nvps = new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = 1025, Name = "Picture 1" };
    var nvpicprops = new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(new PictureLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true });
    var blipFill = new BlipFill(new Blip() { Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart) }, new Stretch(new FillRectangle()));
    var shapeProps = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ShapeProperties(new Transform2D(new Offset() { X = col * cellWidth + offsetX, Y = row * cellHeight + offsetY }, new Extents() { Cx = imageWidth, Cy = imageHeight }), new PresetGeometry(new AdjustValueList()) { Preset = ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle });

    var picture = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Picture(nvps, nvpicprops, blipFill, shapeProps);
    var position = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.AbsoluteAnchor(
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Position() { X = col * cellWidth + offsetX, Y = row * cellHeight + offsetY },
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.Extent() { Cx = imageWidth, Cy = imageHeight }, picture,
            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ClientData());

    drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.WorksheetDrawing(position);
}

Another known good github repository is also not working.
https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/OneCodeTeam/How%20to%20insert%20image%20into%20Excel%20using%20Open%20XML%20SDK/%5BC%23%5D-How%20to%20insert%20image%20into%20Excel%20using%20Open%20XML%20SDK/C%23
